# Companies House API jquery ajax returning 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to return json from gov.uk companies house API but I'm getting a 401

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

I'm using jQuery using the ajax() method and my code looks like this:

```js
var chApiKey = "{{MYAPIKEY}}:";
var company_number = "09963675";

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: company_number,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    //Response text
    alert(data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth(encodeURIComponent(chApiKey)))
    // xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", make_base_auth(chApiKey))
  },
  error: function() {
    //Gat failure
    console.log("error");
  }
});

function make_base_auth(user) {
  // var user = user + ":"
  console.log("the api is: " + user)
  var hash = btoa(user);
  return "Basic " + hash;
  // console.log("Basic " + hash + ":");
}
```

The instructions on [gov.uk](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/readCompanyProfile.html#here) allow you to test with you API key which works. I've also return the json using a curl command in the terminal

```
curl -u{{MYAPIKEY}}: https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/09963675
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, aside from the use of `async: false` which needs to be removed. Check their documentation to ensure that you are encoding your API key correctly, and also that your API key is valid.

Comment: $.ajax allows you to specify `username` and `password` as parameters, you don’t need to create the Authorization header yourself. So try with those instead (specify an empty string for the password), and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I think you get `?` in your URL (like "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company?09963675")

Comment: The key appears to be valid, using their curl example I get a json response as expected.

I can't see any detail about which method to encode the key. They simply say to use the basic html authentification without a password.

Removing the async parameter had no impact on the auth error.

Switching from jsonp to json fires the CORS error, so I've stuck with jsonp for the time being.

I've also tried passing username and password as options rather than setting the header and still the auth error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Propably your get different URL than you expect (with `?`, because that's how `data` in appended in GET request to URL).

You need to add `company_number` to URL (and propably remove `dataType: 'jsonp'`):

```
url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + company_number,
```

Snippet below shows URL for your request in 3 cases:

1. your current code
2. your code after `dataType: 'jsonp'` removal
3. `company_number` added directly to url

```js
var chApiKey = "{{MYAPIKEY}}:";
var company_number = "09963675";

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: company_number,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    //Response text
    alert(data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    console.log("dataType: 'jsonp' :", settings.url)
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth(encodeURIComponent(chApiKey)))
    // xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", make_base_auth(chApiKey))
  },
  error: function() {
    //Gat failure
    //console.log("error");
  }
});

function make_base_auth(user) {
  // var user = user + ":"
  //console.log("the api is: " + user)
  var hash = btoa(user);
  return "Basic " + hash;
  // console.log("Basic " + hash + ":");
}

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: company_number,
  success: function(data) {
    //Response text
    alert(data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    console.log("dataType: 'jsonp' removed  :", settings.url)
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth(encodeURIComponent(chApiKey)))
    // xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", make_base_auth(chApiKey))
  },
  error: function() {
    //Gat failure
    //console.log("error");
  }
});

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + company_number,
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
    //Response text
    alert(data);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    console.log("company number added in url  :", settings.url)
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", make_base_auth(encodeURIComponent(chApiKey)))
    // xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", make_base_auth(chApiKey))
  },
  error: function() {
    //Gat failure
    //console.log("error");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The api returns results without appending a query ? 
Here's their curl example showing this 'curl -uYOUR_APIKEY_FOLLOWED_BY_A_COLON: https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/{company_number}'

Reference page:
[link](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/readCompanyProfile.html)

Comment: That example has no query parameters, although they called it so. Query parameters are added after `?` (like `yoururl.com/subpage?paramname=paramvalue`), but there's no `?` in that example. Your `company_number` should be added to url, because in your example there's `/` between url and this "query parameter". Have you clicked `Run code snippet`? This will show you url you've requested (BTW. propably you should pass "Authorization" header as `"Basic " + btoa(user + ":")` I didn't focus on it in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

In the https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk app settings a field labeled: **JavaScript domains** must:

- include the port number if used
- Can not be localhost

For a local install update the hosts file and update the JavaScripts domains in the app settings.

I had made the mistake of not including the :3000 in this field. so my local domain was http://ch-test.com but should of been http://ch-test.com:3000 as my http server was running on port 3000.

Further to others feedback also changed

dataType: 'jsonp',
=>
dataType: 'json',

async: true,
=>
async: false,